# How to access enum constants from API?

Tags: enums, swift

I want to access an enum from another class.

```
var preferenceButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(288.0, view.bounds.size.height - 32.0, 32.0, 32.0))
preferenceButton.setBackgroundImage(image: UIImage(named: @"preferenceIcon"), forState: UIControlStateNormal) // this does not work, because UIControlStateNormal is not known
```

---

In the Apple docs this is an example

#### OBJECTIVE-C

```
UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

#### SWIFT

```
let myTableView: UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Grouped)
```

*But this does not work for me, maybe because `UITableViewStyleGrouped` is declared in the `UITableView` class?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you imported UIKit?

```
import UIKit
```

You can also try to specify entire name.

```
UITableViewStyle.Grouped
```